# Can we change {APP_NAME} in "via {APP_NAME}" for each shared message to Facebook

Tags: facebook, share

Please have a view at http://screencast.com/t/39uF7lz8I93

Can we hack the {APP_NAME} in "via {APP_NAME}" specialized for each outgoing message to facebook.

My question is not about update the APP_NAME in facebook APP SETINGS but about is there any way to trick it ( I can post to facebook with different APP_NAME from what I have in the settings.

Comment: My question is not about update the APP_NAME in facebook APP SETINGS but about is there any way to trick it ( I can post to facebook with different APP_NAME from what I have in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change that part of a Post via the API - it's hardcoded to the app name

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to show/hide that text. No, right?

Comment: No, if you post via an app, the post is attributed to the app